# How to know if user is a friend using elasticsearch and redis?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, redis, search-engine

I have user data in Elasticsearch and every user's friends in Redis as a ZSET. Client app can search other users from elastic but i want to show if the searched user is a friend or not. Would it be a good approach to check for user keys in ZSET using EXISTS before returning users to client and then show if the user is a friend or not. Or is there a completely different approach to do it. Also is checking for searched users in ZSET an expensive operation. What is a scalable and efficient approach.

Comment: Can you add sample code? or adding your structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depend on average of friends count of Users.

if the average is low(lets say less than 300) you can use your current solution and it's fine.

but if the average is more, **you can set a unique key for each relation between users**, like this:

```
set user-10:friend-of:user-11 true
set user-x:friend-of:user-y true
```

and when you want to recognize if user 20 is friend of user 30, simply just generate the key and check if it's exists on Redis or not.